# Reading "A Convex Darboux Theorem" by Chiappori & Ekeland

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

This is cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452087/ but got no reply

---

I am reading "A Convex Darboux Theorem" by Chiappori and Ekeland [1]. I do not pretend to understand the proof but just want to make sure that I understand their result.

They start with a 1-form
$$ \tilde \omega = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \omega_n dx^n \tag{1}\label{1}$$ and are asking when for a given $K \lt N $ can $\tilde \omega$ can be reduced to a specific form such as

$$ \tilde \omega = \sum_{k=1}^{K} a^k du_k \tag{2}\label{2}$$ where the functions $a^k(\{x^n\})\gt 0$ and the functions $u_k(\{x^n\})$ are concave $\cap$.
This would be a special case of the Frobenius-Darboux theorem that says that the reduction of $\eqref{1}$ to $\eqref{2}$ can be had if and only if
$$\tilde \omega \wedge (d\tilde \omega )^K = 0 \\\tilde \omega \wedge (d\tilde \omega )^{K-1} \ne 0 \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Now Chiappori-Ekeland claim that such decomposition can exist for an analytic form $\tilde \omega$ if and only if the matrix of partial derivatives $\Omega_{n,m} = \frac {\partial \omega_m}{\partial x^n}$ can be written as the sum of a negative definite matrix and one that has rank $K$: $\mathbf {\Omega} = \mathbf Q + \mathbf R$ and $\mathbf Q \le 0$, $rank\{\mathbf R\} = K$

A simple substitution shows that $$\Omega_{n,m} = \frac {\partial \omega_m}{\partial x^n} = \sum_{k=1}^{K} a^k \frac{\partial^2 u_k}{\partial x^n\partial x^m} + \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{\partial a^k}{\partial x^n}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x^m}$$

Let us take the simplest (?) special case of $K=1$, so we are talking about the existence of a positive integrating factor and assume that we just happen to have that $\Omega_{n,m}$ is indeed a negative (semi)-definite matrix. Then if I understand correctly there is a positive function $a=1$ and a concave $\cap$ function $u$ such that $$ \tilde \omega = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \omega_n dx^n = du \tag{4}\label{4}$$

$\bf{Question}$: Is this a *correct* interpretation of the result in [1]?

---

[1] Chiappori and Ekeland: A Convex Darboux Theorem, http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASNSP_1997_4_25_1-2_287_0

Comment: This seems relevant: 1. http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/MAA.2002.v9.n3.a3 2. https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07100

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you, I am trying to digest them (not easy)